# Does Rust provide a way to parse integer numbers directly from ASCII data in byte (u8) arrays?

Tags: string, rust

Rust has [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str), however as far as I can see this only takes Unicode text input. Is there an equivalent to this for `[u8]` arrays?

By "parse" I mean take ASCII characters and return an integer, like C's `atoi` does.

Or do I need to either...

- Convert the `u8` array to a string first, then call `FromStr`.
- Call out to libc's `atoi`.
- Write an `atoi` in Rust.

In nearly all cases the first option is reasonable, however there are cases where files maybe be very large, with no predefined encoding... or contain mixed binary and text, where its most straightforward to read integer numbers as bytes.

Comment: If you have mixed binary and text in a custom format, perhaps you should parse the *whole file* using a parser such as [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom).

Comment: What does it matter if the file is large? You just convert to string the slice you know contains the number: `i32::from_str(str::from_utf8(&data[a..b]).unwrap()).unwrap()`. IIRC, that is zero-copy.

Comment: File being large is just a note that it may contain GB of data, so a more optimal method which doesn't use an extra conversion and intermediate storage may be preferred in some cases, even with `from_utf8`, I expect the code-path does multi-byte characters checks? if we know the data is an array of digits, its not such a problem to write an `atoi`, admittedly this isn't a typical use-case.

Comment: @ideasman42: To avoid multi-bytes check you always have [`from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html), of course it's unsafe.

Answer (score 21):

No, the standard library has no such feature, but it doesn't need one.

As stated in the comments, the raw bytes can be converted to a `&str` via:

1. [`str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html)
2. [`str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html)

Neither of these perform extra allocation. The first one ensures the bytes are valid UTF-8, the second does not. Everyone should use the checked form until such time as **profiling** proves that it's a bottleneck, then use the unchecked form once it's proven safe to do so.

If bytes deeper in the data need to be parsed, a *slice* of the raw bytes can be obtained before conversion:

```
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let raw_data = b"123132";

    let the_bytes = &raw_data[1..4];
    let the_string = str::from_utf8(the_bytes).expect("not UTF-8");
    let the_number: u64 = the_string.parse().expect("not a number");

    assert_eq!(the_number, 231);
}
```

As in other code, these these lines can be extracted into a function or a trait to allow for reuse. However, once that path is followed, it would be a good idea to look into one of the many great [crates aimed at parsing](https://crates.io/search?q=parsing). This is especially true if there's a need to parse binary data in addition to textual data.

Comment: Parsing bytes can come useful in high-performance applications. `str::from_utf8()` checks that the string is valid UTF-8, which has a cost, and is redundant if the content will be verified by the parser anyway. `str::from_utf8_unchecked()` is UB if there is a possibility for bytes to contain non-UTF8 content, so it can't be used with untrusted data. Example use case: reading of a large CSV file using `csv::Reader::into_byte_records()`, and converting a field to number.

Comment: The methods you link in your solution do not take strings and return integers. The method that you're using to actually do so is [`std::str#parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse). If you could please update your answer to properly reflect that, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Andria yes, they are not intended to. As the title of the question states: *... directly from ASCII data **in byte (u8) arrays***. The OP specifically does not want strings.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Shepmaster. I'm not saying that OP wants strings or that your answer is wrong. I'm just saying that your answer uses `std::str#parse` but does not explain that or link to it in any way, and it would be beneficial to see that part of the answer be more detailed

Answer (score 8):

I do not know of any way in the standard library, but maybe the [atoi](https://crates.io/crates/atoi) crate works for you? Full disclosure: I am its author.

```
use atoi::atoi;

let (number, digits) = atoi::<u32>(b"42 is the answer"); //returns (42,2)
```

You can check if the second element of the tuple is a zero to see if the slice starts with a digit.

```
let (number, digits) = atoi::<u32>(b"x"); //returns (0,0)
let (number, digits) = atoi::<u32>(b"0"); //returns (0,1)
```