# How can I convert an [u8] hex ascii representation to a u64

Tags: rust

I would like to convert my bytes array into a u64.

For example
`b"00"` should return 0u64
`b"0a"` should return 10u64

I am working on blockchain, so I must find something efficient.
For example, my current function is not efficient at all.

```rust
let number_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&my_bytes_array)
            .to_owned()
            .to_string();
let number = u64::from_str_radix(&number_string , 16).unwrap();
```

I have also tried

```rust
let number = u64::from_le_bytes(my_bytes_array);
```

But I got this error `mismatched types expected array [u8; 8], found &[u8]`

Comment: How big are these numbers? For reasonably-sized numbers (read: at most 100 digits or so), that string construction is *not* going to be your bottleneck. Unless you've already profiled and found that that's a definite problem for your use case, I think this is a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Hey, thank for you your comment. The numbers I am working with don't exceed 5 digits. I started optimization after seeing the high fees of my functions. This came from the string allocation being badly handled by the blockchain I am working on.

Comment: The allocation for the `String` may be using most of the resources. Try using [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) instead. Or [`std::str::from_utf8_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html) if you know it's valid utf8.

Comment: You allocate _twice_, both of them are redundant! `String::from_utf8_lossy()` alone is enough, or better justt `str::from_utf8()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Rust provide a way to parse integer numbers directly from ASCII data in byte (u8) arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404265/does-rust-provide-a-way-to-parse-integer-numbers-directly-from-ascii-data-in-byt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```rust
pub fn hex_to_u64(x: &[u8]) -> Option<u64> {
    let mut result: u64 = 0;
    for i in x {
        result *= 16;
        result += (*i as char).to_digit(16)? as u64;
    }
    Some(result)
}
```

Comment: Would it be more clear with the bitwise operator `<<= 4` instead of `*= 16`?