# How do I convert a separated series of "digits"?

Tags: rust

The vector `m` contains "digits" from `48` through `57`, `48` corresponding to `0`, `49` to `1` etc. Numbers are separated by the occurence of `13, 10` in sequence. How to get the result `[1073, 8705]` for `n` in the example below?

```
fn main() {

  let m: Vec<u8> = vec![49, 48, 55, 51, 13, 10, 56, 55, 48, 53, 13, 10];
  let mut n: Vec<u32> = vec![];

  println!("m = {:?}", m);
  println!("n = {:?}", n);

  //  ...
  
  println!("n = {:?}", n); // ? how get: [1073, 8705]
}

/*
0 - 48
1 - 49
2 - 50
3 - 51
4 - 52
5 - 53
6 - 54
7 - 55
8 - 56
9 - 57
*/
```

[play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6248b4458a309b156333c267f34ddd74)

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes it's in the sense that the vector is composed of the values in that set, plus the [10, 13] separator. This is basically a list of ASCII numbers, separated by windows-style newlines (CRLF).

Comment: That's what I inferred, as such while not the most efficient the easiest way by far is to decode to a string using [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html), then use the [`str::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) iterators which handles the linebreaks, and finally map [`parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) onto each item, ending up with an iterator of numbers.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404265/does-rust-provide-a-way-to-parse-integer-numbers-directly-from-ascii-data-in-byt?

Comment: @Masklinn,
println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&[49]).unwrap().parse::<i32>().unwrap());

Comment: `std::str::from_utf8 (&m[..]).unwrap().lines().map (str::parse::<u32>).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>().unwrap()` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2dee6ac9036739f876ec9ee1b4a51a03))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is a small runtime impact due to the use of strings, I would still prefer the mature parsing functionality of Rust:

```
let v: Vec<u8> = vec![49, 48, 55, 51, 13, 10, 56, 55, 48, 53, 13, 10];
let s: String = String::from_utf8(v).unwrap();

let n: Vec<_> = s.lines().map(|n| n.parse::<u32>().unwrap()).collect();
println!("{n:?}");
```

Change `n.parse::<u32>()` to `n.parse::<String>()` for a string array.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f3aafcfe5c9b27e25fbb9c45baf8fa7)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go through String, you can parse manually.

```rust
fn main() {
    let m = vec![49_u8, 48, 55, 51, 13, 10, 56, 55, 48, 53, 13, 10];

    let mut curr_num = 0_u32;
    let mut curr_is_nonempty = false;
    let mut nums = Vec::new();

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < m.len() {
        if &m[i..i + 2] == &[13, 10] {
            nums.push(curr_num);
            curr_num = 0;
            curr_is_nonempty = false;
            i += 2;
            continue;
        }

        let val = (m[i] - b'0') as u32;
        curr_num = 10 * curr_num + val;
        curr_is_nonempty = true;

        i += 1;
    }

    if curr_is_nonempty {
        nums.push(curr_num);
    }

    println!("m = {:?}", m);
    println!("n = {:?}", nums);
}
```

Comment: [Jmb_link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2dee6ac9036739f876ec9ee1b4a51a03)  ,  [my_link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25c9ab23a469b1528c078dd1ab5e718d)